# Rectangle marker style matplotlib / seaborn scatterplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn scatter plot's style parameter to use different marker styles for one of my categorical column which allows me to explicitly choose which marker symbol I prefer for a specific category.

I can use the symbols in the following link without any problem: https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html

However, I want one of the symbols to be a rectangle, but there is no rectangle option here. Is there any way to make rectangle ONE of the symbols and also see it in the legend seamlessly?

Comment: You could use hline ('_') or vline ('|') and set a larger size

Comment: See [Marker Path](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/marker_path.html) to create custom markers

Comment: @JohanC unfortunately, hline or vline gives this error:

"Filled and line art markers cannot be mixed"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One fairly simple solution is to use STIX font symbols for [the markers](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html). You can consult a list (I don't know if exhasutive) [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf)

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
plt.figure()
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                     hue="time", style="time", data=tips, markers={'Dinner':'$\u25A0$', 'Lunch':'$\u25AC$'}, s=50)
```

[image]